# Restful service issue on free hosting server using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, restful-architecture

I am using chrome extension for restful service testing.
It is giving me status 200 OK but redirecting me to free hosting server error page.
I don't know where i am doing mistake.
Please help me out for this, below is there redirecting error and status code 200 shown by client.

```
**Redirect**
To:http://error404.000webhost.com/? with status: 302 Show explanation HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Redirection information has not been cached.
Date: Sun, 13 Apr 2014 07:55:55 GMT 
Server: Apache 
Location: http://error404.000webhost.com/? 
Content-Length: 216 
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 
**Status**
200 OK **Show explanation** Loading time: 1292
```

Comment: It sounds like your link doesn't exist but the webhost has a special `404 Not Found` page that they're redirecting you to which is why you get `302 Found` then `200 OK` for the 404 page.

Comment: 302 is temporary redirection. Check if the url called is correct. If it is, check with the hosting service provider

Comment: i am using Following link
http://life-flow.net23.net/rest/users/
life-flow.net23.net is my domain hosted on 000webhost
is this a correct link ???

Comment: And which script is handling that address? Do you have some .htaccess redirection via mod_rewrite? Or, do you use 404 redirection via ErrorPage?

Comment: you are right i have solved my problem by correcting .htaccess file